# Resetting Secure Boot Keys

Tags: boot, security, reset

What will happen if I choose the "Reset To Setup Mode" option in the AMI Aptio Setup? Will I irrevocably lose all the keys there are including the factory ones? Or the factory keys cannot be wiped out from NVRAM, and I'll be able to use them in the Setup Mode upon reset?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the primary function of Setup Mode is just to remove the PK (Platform Key). The PK is the outermost "lock" that prevents other Secure Boot keys from being changed, so with it removed you're allowed to freely change KEK/db/dbx entries – or to install a custom PK, of course.

This means that selecting Setup Mode most likely *won't* remove anything from KEK or db – the PC firmwares I've seen usually have a separate "Clear" function to achieve that.

> Will I irrevocably lose all the keys there are including the factory ones? Or the factory keys cannot be wiped out from NVRAM, and I'll be able to use them in the Setup Mode upon reset?

Yes and no. The "live" EFI variables related to Secure Boot (db, KEK, PK) may be wiped out completely if you ask for that to happen, but UEFI also has "backup" ones (dbDefault, KEKDefault, etc.) which are read-only and will always have their original values. This lets you or the firmware restore to its original state with Microsoft+OEM keys even if those *are* wiped out.

Keep in mind that none of the Secure Boot variables store any *private* keys, and they rarely if ever contain anything unique to your system. They only contain public X.509 certificates, and usually their values are either widely known (KEK and db typically contain only Microsoft and manufacturer CAs) or completely inconsequential (the existence of a PK certificate matters more than its contents).

Comment: Does this mean that "Reset to Setup Mode" option clears factory keys also? Or I will be able to load them from NVRAM after the reset?

Comment: There's a decent VMWare article about secure boot here --> https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2017/05/secure-boot-esxi-6-5-hypervisor-assurance.html
There's also a couple of powershell commands called Get-SecureBootUEFI, Set-SecureBootUEFI, and Format-SecureBootUEFI that allow you to work with the PK, KEK, db, dbx, SetupMode, SecureBoot, and dbt sections.

Comment: @AcadEmic: It clears factory keys from the "current" PK/KEK/db variables (removing PK is what enables Setup Mode), but not from the "default" PKDefault/KEKDefault/dbDefault variables (so there is always another option to return to factory keys as well).